# Validate username and password in Microsoft VIsual Studio

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I am having trouble validating a username and password when someone clicks a button. I have two text boxes named `user_logon_id` and `user_password`.

I have a table called *MyUsers* that I suppose to verify that both the username (user_logon_id) and password (user_password) are in the same row. If they do not match, it's supposed to notify the user. If it does match then direct them to `userAdmin.aspx`.

I am using Microsoft [Visual Studio 2008](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2008). I am really new to this and would really like to get a grasp on this. I do not need to worry about encrypting the password.

Comment: `"I do not need to worry about encrypting the password."`  No, but you should worry about hashing the password.  Even if it's not an explicitly stated requirement, it should always be done.

Comment: Do you get any errors? What is causing trouble here? Change your query to check username and password and return row count in one sql and then use execute scalar to get count and based on count authenticate user.

Comment: To say nothing of SQL Injection ...

Comment: What is the problem? You never actually ask us a question, is the code not working? If so what error do you get or what's wrong with it?  If your question is "*I don't know how to do this, can you do it for me?*" then the answer is "*NO*".

Comment: Sorry, When I load the page and type in a username and password and click submit nothing happens. Even if I type a correct username and password. I'm not asking for the answer to this, I want to learn how to do this right. Maybe someone can point out a section of the code that needs to be fixed.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will do some research on hashing and review the code posted by erikdc.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Can you run this in the debugger and verify that the query is returning a row?

Some suggestions:

Consider parameterizing your query like this:

```
 Dim conn As New SqlConnection(_connectionString)
 conn.Open()
 Dim s As String = "SELECT user_password FROM MyUsers WHERE user_logon_id = @user_login_id"
 Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(s)
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@user_login_id", Me.user_logon_id.Text)
 Dim reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
```

Hash the password in some way

Consider selecting from the database table where the username and password match. If the result is one record the login succeeded.

```
     Dim s As String = "SELECT userid FROM MyUsers WHERE user_logon_id = @user_login_id and user_password=@user_password"
```

Full code

```
Protected Sub butSubmit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles butSubmit.Click

Dim myReader As Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader
Dim mySqlConnection As Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
Dim mySqlCommand As Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand

'Establish the SqlConnection by using the configuration manager to get the connection string in our web.config file.
mySqlConnection = New Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString1").ToString())
Dim sql As String = "SELECT userid FROM MyUsers WHERE user_logon_id = @user_login_id and user_password=@user_password"

mySqlCommand = New Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(sql, mySqlConnection)

 cmd.Parameters.Add("@user_login_id", Me.user_logon_id.Text)
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@user_password", Me.user_password.Text)

Try
    mySqlConnection.Open()
    myReader = mySqlCommand.ExecuteReader()

    If (myReader.HasRows) Then    
            'Open page with users and roles
            Dim message As String = "Correct password"
            Dim style As MsgBoxStyle = MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly
            Dim title As String = "Authenticated"
            MsgBox(message, style, title)
    End If

Catch ex As Exception
    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString())
Finally
    If Not (myReader Is Nothing) Then
        myReader.Close()
    End If

    If (mySqlConnection.State = Data.ConnectionState.Open) Then
        mySqlConnection.Close()
    End If

End Try

End Sub
```